# What versions of ClojureScript and Closure am I using with lein-cljsbuild?

Tags: version, clojurescript, google-closure

I'm using lein-cljsbuild 0.2.10. What versions of ClojureScript and Closure is it using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find some answers in the [project file for cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/master/support/project.clj): it seems that lein-cljsbuild 0.2.10 depends on ClojureScript 0.0-1552 and Closure 20120710-r2029

Please try not to ask more than one question at once.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wrote the question when I was annoyed that that information wasn't readily available. I edited my question and I will now ask two other questions related to API documentation for the two libraries. Thank you, Maurits.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to specify the versions of Clojure and ClojureScript you would like it to use in the dependencies section of your project.clj.