# ClojureScript API documentation

Tags: api, documentation, clojurescript

I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067266/what-versions-of-clojurescript-and-closure-am-i-using-with-lein-cljsbuild/14076585#14076585) how to find out which version of ClojureScript I'm using with lein-cljsbuild. Where can I find API documentation for cljs.core?

I had to find out about js-obj from a blog post.

I [can look at the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1552/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs), but it's a large file and it's mostly clojure.core stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly thorough documentation, but this cheat sheet is really quite helpful when starting out (and better than nothing!):

http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/Others/ClojureScript%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf

Answer (score 3):

ClojureScript definitely has a documentation problem. You're actually not too bad off looking at the source; it's verbose but not too bad once you get used to it.

That said, one of the reasons nobody has produced a definitive ClojureScript API reference is that the core functions all mirror Clojure, so it would be quite a lot of redundant effort. If a function exists in both languages and doesn't work the same way, it's highly unusual and quite possibly a bug.

In practice, I find that using the Clojure API docs (or something like clojuredocs.org) coupled with very occasional forays into the source code work pretty well for 99% of my cljs work.

Comment: js-obj is in cljs.core which is only *mostly* mirroring Clojure. That function is essential for interop. I up-voted but didn't accept because you answered my question (the documentation doesn't exist), but I hope it will someday. :)

Answer (score 2):

ClojureScript API Documentation is being worked on here:
http://cljs.github.io/api